# Why does readmatrix in Matlab skip the first n lines?

Tags: matlab, csv, file

In my simulation I am writing data to file using `writematrix`, then later reading it back using `readmatrix`. I am appending to a single file at each time step, each line is the same length or longer than the previous line.

For some reason when using `readmatrix` on the output file, the first n lines are skipped entirely, as in not read at all. For example, my file looks like this:

```
...
11.8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2
11.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2
...
12.3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2
12.4,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10,1,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,1
12.5,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10,1,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,1
...
30.5,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,2
30.6,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,2
30.7,17,18,19,20,1,2,7,8,9,10,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,2,11,12,13,14,15,16,7,8,9,10,1
30.8,17,18,19,20,1,2,7,8,9,10,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,2,11,12,13,14,15,16,7,8,9,10,1
...
```

(the first column is a time stamp, so the first ellipsis represents t=0 to t=11.7. At t=30.7 there is another step jump in the number of entries), and when I read using the command

```
data = readmatrix('/path/to/file/data.csv');
```

the matrix `data` looks like

```
12.4 7 8 9 10 7 8 9 10 1 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 1
12.5 7 8 9 10 7 8 9 10 1 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 1
12.6 7 8 9 10 7 8 9 10 1 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 1
...
30.5 7 8 9 10 7 8 9 10 1 2 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 2
30.6 7 8 9 10 7 8 9 10 1 2 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 2
30.7 17 18 19 20 1 2 7 8 9 10 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 2 11 12 13 14 15 16 7 8 9 10 1
30.8 17 18 19 20 1 2 7 8 9 10 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 2 11 12 13 14 15 16 7 8 9 10 1
...
```

That is to say, all the entries before t=12.4 (i.e. the first step jump in line length) are skipped.
In the file, if I delete everything before the first step jump (i.e everything before t=12.4), then I get the same matrix `data`, so we can conclude the subsequent step jumps cause no issue. If I delete everything from the second step jump (i.e. everything after t=30.6) then it still skips all the entries before t=12.4. If I have no step jumps (i.e. only t=0 to t=12.3) then it happily reads in the first lines.

I've tried reading the same file using `csvread` and it returns all of the data from the beginning of the file (albeit padded with zeros instead of nans), so I'm confident the issue isn't with the file.

Why is this happening?

A minimum working example is the first code block without the ellipses.

For reference, the first lines have 12 csvs, and each step jump increase that by 11

Edit:

Output from `detectImportOptions`

```
ans = 

  DelimitedTextImportOptions with properties:

   Format Properties:
                    Delimiter: {','}
                   Whitespace: '\b\t '
                   LineEnding: {'\n'  '\r'  '\r\n'}
                 CommentStyle: {}
    ConsecutiveDelimitersRule: 'split'
        LeadingDelimitersRule: 'keep'
                EmptyLineRule: 'skip'
                     Encoding: 'UTF-8'

   Replacement Properties:
                  MissingRule: 'fill'
              ImportErrorRule: 'fill'
             ExtraColumnsRule: 'addvars'

   Variable Import Properties: Set types by name using setvartype
                VariableNames: {'Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3' ... and 20 more}
                VariableTypes: {'double', 'double', 'double' ... and 20 more}
        SelectedVariableNames: {'Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3' ... and 20 more}
              VariableOptions: Show all 23 VariableOptions 
    Access VariableOptions sub-properties using setvaropts/getvaropts
        PreserveVariableNames: false

   Location Properties:
                    DataLines: [4 Inf]
            VariableNamesLine: 0
               RowNamesColumn: 0
            VariableUnitsLine: 0
     VariableDescriptionsLine: 0 
    To display a preview of the table, use preview
```

Comment: Try running `detectImportOptions()` on your file and see what that tells you. I bet `readmatrix` is trying to be "smart" and find the region which is actually a 2-D matrix.

Comment: @AndrewJanke, thanks for that tip. I've had a look and I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. There's a line that says `EmptyLineRule: 'skip'` so perhaps it's treating it as an empty line? From the documentation `detectImportOptions` looks like it's meant for tables - I don't know how to translate that information to the context of `readmatrix`

Comment: Could you just post the full display of the `detectImportOptions` results as part of your question, so we can see it? And maybe a link to download one of your CSV files so we can reproduce easily?

Comment: I've added the output. If you copy the first code block with the example data, remove the lines with ellipses and name it test.csv, it will give the same result. As a side note, I'm using 2020a

Comment: That `DataLines: [4 Inf]` looks suspicious. What happens if you force it to `[1 Inf]` and then call `readmatrix`, explicitly passing in the modified `DelimitedTextImportOptions` object you have?

Comment: @AndrewJanke yep that fixes it! Well spotted. Thanks for your heIp! It seems you were right, matlab was indeed trying to be too smart :) That gives me a working solution, but I can't help wondering if there's way to stop it doing this in the first place...

Comment: If you want to do it properly from the start, call `readmatrix(path2mat,delimitedTextImportOptions('DataLines',[0,Inf]))` and specify the options right away. There is no default setting of this [option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.text.delimitedtextimportoptions.html), so perhaps there is something in the 4th line of your file that MATLAB make believe that this is a header...

Comment: Sweet! I've converted my comments to an answer and fleshed it out with @max's better approach. (Thanks @max!) Would you mind Accepting it if this worked out for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab's `readmatrix` is trying to be smart and locate a 2-D matrix within the data model of the CSV file you're passing it. It looks like it's passing over the first few lines which don't have explicit trailing empty "cells".

You can control this by setting the import options. Run `opts = detectImportOptions(...);` on your file and have a look at the `DataLines` property. If it doesn't start at 1, set it to `[1 Inf]` to force `readmatrix` to read in all the lines. And then call `readmatrix`, explicitly passing in that options structure.

To do this compactly (and probably more efficiently), call `readmatrix` with an explicit option right off the bat like this:

```matlab
readmatrix(path2mat,delimitedTextImportOptions('DataLines',[0,Inf]))
```